# Find a substring after 2nd occurrence of delimiter

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a formula that help find a substring after second occurrence of a certain delimiter. For example, in below string, I want the substring that exists after the 2nd dash “-“ i.e. Ccc. Could you please suggest how can I do that?

Aaa-Bbb-**Ccc**-Ddd

Comment: What have you tried? What are the results of those attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Werrf and Zac67 are both on the right track here. If you don't know how long the `ccc` portion is, then you need to find the 2nd *and* 3rd dash.

```
=LET(dash2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","|",2)),dash3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","|",3)),MID(A1,dash2+1,dash3-dash2-1))
```

That seems really long but it's not complicated. The `LET()` function allows you to define variables and reference them by name later. The terms all come in pairs (`variable, value`) except the last term which is the output. Here are those terms in order:

- `dash2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","|",2))` is like what Werrf provided to find the second dash. It's important that the replacement character is guaranteed to not appear in your string. Werrf and I both use the pipe `|` because it's so rarely used in normal text.
- `dash3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","|",3))` is the exact same thing except it finds the third pipe. You could also use `FIND("-",A1,dash2+1)` instead of the substitute thing if the length is bothersome but I like keeping them the same.
- `MID(A1,dash2+1,dash3-dash2-1)` extracts the middle of the text based on where it found the 2nd dash and the distance between the 2nd and 3rd dashes.

---

If you find it annoying to change all the `A1` references, you could specify that as the first variable:

```
=LET(a,A1,dash2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(a,"-","|",2)),dash3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(a,"-","|",3)),MID(a,dash2+1,dash3-dash2-1))
```

or

```
=LET(a,A1,dash2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(a,"-","|",2)),dash3,FIND("-",a,dash2+1),MID(a,dash2+1,dash3-dash2-1))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This did it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the lengths of the delimited sections you need to nest multiple `search()` functions:

```
=search("-",haystack,search("-",haystack)+1)+1
```

tells you the start index after the second "-".

Comment: This gave me error

Comment: @NikhilTamhankar Try a , instead of ; (which the German version uses).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SUBSTITUTE` function to replace the delimiter you're looking for. `SUBSTITUTE` allows you search for a specific character and replace it with another; crucially, you can also specify which occurrence of the character you want to replace. We'll use it to replace the second delimiter with another character that we can then search for - I like to use the Pipe `|`.  Assuming the string you're checking is in A1, use:

```
SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","|",2)
```

This would return Aaa-Bbb|Ccc-Ddd.  You can then use `MID` and either `FIND` or `SEARCH` to return the rest of the string:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","|",2)),LEN(A1))
```

This will return: -Ccc-Ddd

Comment: This is good but I only need Ccc without dashes or next word.

I don't know the length of the Ccc as well.

Answer (score 1):

All versions but may have a problem on very long strings:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),198,99))
```

Windows Excel 2013+

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[3]")
```

With the Insiders version of Office 365, you can also use the `TEXTSPLIT` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+1)+1,FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",1,1))-FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

[image]